# How to determine PDF of such complicated expression?

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

I am trying to obtain PDF of $\gamma$ but not getting it correctly.

$\gamma = |\sum_{r=1}^R\mu_r|^2$----(1)

where R is some number and $\mu_r$ is a independent and identically distributed random variable with PDF given by

$f_{|\mu_r|}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2k+1}}{\sigma^{2k+1}_1}W_{-k-0.5,0}(2\delta)\times\frac{2}{\sqrt{\alpha^2\sigma^2_2\sigma^2_3}}e^{\delta-\frac{x^2}{\sigma^2_1}}$

where $W_{a,b}(\cdot)$ is Whittaker function and all other elements are constants.

My query is how to obtain PDF of $\gamma$.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Using your statistics knowledge, is there any way to solve for $\mu_r$? If so, we can put $f_{|\mu_r|}(x)$ in terms of $\gamma$

Comment: Thank you so much for your response....I observe that there is summation of $\mu_r$. So we cannot use the convolution operation . However we can go with MGF (moment generating function) of $\mu_r$. But I am not getting how to get PDF of $\gamma$ from MGF.